# How to copy a file in endless running batch file only if file not existing in target directory?

Tags: batch-file

I want to copy a Microsoft Excel file from source folder to destination folder with the condition to copy the file only if it does not exist in destination folder. I want this command being executed in a loop which is run endless with a wait time of 3 seconds between each execution.

Below is my batch file:

```
:start
If Not Exist D:\Users\00002829\Downloads\QAS\QAS.xls xcopy "D:\Users\00002829\Downloads\Origin" "D:\Users\00002829\Downloads\QAS"
(
timeout /t 3
)
goto start
```

But this batch file is not working. It copies always the file even if the file exists in destination folder.

Comment: You are not telling it to copy a specific file.  The source needs to have the file name.

Comment: Are you sure that inside `Origin` folder there is a file called `QAS.xls`?

Comment: As implied by @Squashman, your question is about copying a file, but your code is trying to copy a directory to a directory. You should therefore use `XCopy` or `Copy` to copy a specific file, or edit your question to make it clear that you're copying a directory. In any case, to find out how to use a command, open a Command Prompt and enter the command name followed by a space, slash and question mark, e.g. `XCopy /?`.

Comment: Run `help robocopy`, especially the `/Mon:n` and `/Mot:m` options.

Comment: Thx guys, I already found solution. Thanks to @Ceasar Montes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As everyone suggested, you are not specifying the file to be copied.
Also, for a single file I rather prefer to use `copy`; keep it simple. However, do notice that, if that file (qas.xls) is being used, you may want to switch to `robocopy` and take advantages of his almost infinite options.

The suggested code:

```
:start
if not exist "d:\users\00002829\downloads\qas\qas.xls" (
    xcopy "d:\users\00002829\downloads\origin\qas.xls" "d:\users\00002829\downloads\qas"
)
timeout /t 3
goto start
```